# Find username with LDAP

Tags: php, authentication, ldap

I maintain an intranet web site for a large company. Since a failure of current user authentication system, I had to develop an urgent solution.
Here is the simplified code

```
$usr=$_POST['user'];
$psw=$_POST['code'];

if(!strlen($psw) )
$psw="x";
// because empty password works fine for any user

$ldap= ldap_connect("LDAP://ldapserver.xxx.local");
if(!$ldap)
exit(0);

ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

if($bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $usr, $psw){
header("Location: http:10.xx.xx.xx/entrance.php?id=$usr");
// login OK, look for user privileges
}else{
header("Location: http:10.xx.xx.xx/login.php?INV=1");
// back to login page
}
```

The code works just fine, but I don't want users have to enter their network user name and password,
when a user comes to this page, connect and bind anonymously to LDAP server, could a page get information about username of this user.

And it would be a great bonus if it could give, some extra info such as full name, branch code, branch, mail addr ..   etc

Comment: Well you WILL have to ask for the login credentials to enable LDAP server to grant authentication to the user session

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your LDAP server. If it requires authentication, you'll have to provide that information; however, this ought to be delegated to some service account, rather than bound to a specific user (which is an entirely different process). Anyway, presuming that isn't a problem, you can query an LDAP server using `ldap_search`.

For example, if you wanted to search for a username of `cihats`, under the `o=example` DN, the following would do the trick:

```
$ldap = @ldap_connect($yourHostname);
$query = @ldap_search($ldap, 'o=example', 'cn=cihats');
$results = @ldap_get_entries($ldap, $query);

if ($results['count']) {
  print_r($results);
} else {
  echo "No such common name";
}
```

The output of `ldap_get_entries` will be the whole directory for each of the matches found in the search, so you will be able to get things like the full name, branch codes, etc., but these will have site specific keys.